# no auto completion on Eclipse after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, xubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Eclipse (both Juno and Kepler) started crashing after the Ubuntu upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04.
They're not crashing after adding:

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to `configuration/config.ini`

(from https://askubuntu.com/questions/457506)

But now the auto-completion has gone.
I updated to java 8, added 
    org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/bin/xulrunner
to `configuration/config.ini`, using both `xulrunner` 20 and 29. To no avail.
(from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776 )

Even a re-install of Kepler doesn't fix the issue.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out that the content assist was there all along (it's working when selected from the context menu). But CTRL+space was highjacked by the input method (IBus). I've deleted the key in the input method and got the content assist back straight away.

Comment: How can I do that? In my ubuntu setting I have two shortcuts menu, one for "windowd" and one for "keyboard" but I can't find ctrl+space combination. xubuntu 14.04 keyboard language=italian. Thanks

Comment: Great, that it works for you two lightbulbs...

After searching a while, I found the solution, and I will share it with the others: You have to go to the "IBus preferences". Here I found a description how to get there: http://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-openoffice-chinese-preferences.htm (first picture). On the second picture you see the input field beneath "Enable or disable". You have to click the button "..." and delete the entry for Ctrl+Space.

Comment: thank you @nyx. As a note to other visitors: In Xubuntu it is Settings -> Settings Manager -> Keyboard Input Methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Kepler and Aptana Studio in Ubuntu 14.04 64 without any issues. I'm using the Oracle 1.7 JDK/JRE, which I installed manually. That includes creating links to java, javaws in /usr/local/bin. Other than that, I haven't tweaked anything I can think of. I hope that helps; telling you it works for me isn't much help...

Comment: Indeed it was working for me in a fresh ubuntu install, so that got me thinking about why it would affect some users and not others.